# Custom error message in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I would like to display a custom error message when users try to access my website, and it is not reachable. Instead of - Internet Explorer cannot open the Internet site, I want to show, "We are currently down for maintenance. Please be patient. We'll be back!".

Please suggest how do I achieve this?

Comment: please configure 404 page in web.xml

Comment: @Rugal web server is down for maintainance

Comment: you can make a configuration, while let `apache` to cope with static file such as `404` or `500` page, and then forward other dynamical request into tomcat or other servlet container

Comment: in addition, you can configure an extra server to do the static file issues

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing things. The error message

```
Internet Explorer cannot open the Internet site
```

given by Internet Explorer just means it can't connect to your web server. It's not something your application can control.

What you can control is what is returned in the case of any error that occurs in your application or any status your application is in. For example, for a 503 Service Unavailable you can render a special JSP.

How you do this is up to you. You have to first figure out that the service is unavailable (or some other cause), whatever that means to your application, and then produce an appropriate http response with an appropriate status code. The standard status codes can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Comment: we can go for http server to do this job when the web server is unavailable

Comment: @Sotirios - Yes, you are right. I basically want to show a custom error with a custom icon when my web server is not reachable. Similar to what most websites have these days, Groupon etc. I have no clue how  to do this :(

Comment: @user2852629 Write up jsp that shows an error message. `forward()` to that jsp when you've decided that the service is unavailable or when there's an internal server error, etc.